# Using connect-history-api-fallback middleware in FeathersJS for serving Vue.js SPA

Tags: node.js, express, single-page-application, feathersjs

As the title suggests, I'm serving a Vue.js single page application from `public/index.html` in FeathersJS. Since I'm using vue-router's HTML5 history mode, I have to use a middleware like [`connect-history-api-fallback`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback) in order to rewrite the requested frontend location to `/index.html`.

Setting up this middleware in `src/middleware` just before `app.use(notFound());` doesn't work since Feathers serves the static files before everything else, so by the time the request gets rewritten nothing picks up `/index.html` and `notFound` serves a 404 response.

Configuring it before `.use('/', serveStatic(app.get('public')))` inside `src/app.js` is also problematic since it will rewrite every service request to `/index.html`, making API calls unreachable.

I ended up moving the `serveStatic` middleware after `.configure(services)` and placing `connect-history-api-fallback` right above like so:

```
app.use(compress())
  .options('*', cors())
  .use(cors())
  // favicon and serveStatic used to be here
  .use(bodyParser.json())
  .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
  .configure(hooks())
  .configure(rest())
  .configure(socketio())
  .configure(services)
  .use(require('connect-history-api-fallback')())
  // now they are down here
  .use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')))
  .use('/', serveStatic(app.get('public')))
  .configure(middleware);
```

**My question is the following:** Are there any performance or security drawbacks to this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the configuration you posted, there aren't really any security concerns.

If you were to replace your `serveStatic` middleware with SSR middleware, you would want to delete the CORS headers before the SSR middleware to avoid leaking data through Cross Site Requests (CSRF "attacks" using cookies).